# OSPF DR election

Tags: ethernet, ospf

From what I know, DR and BDRs are elected in an area which has an Ethernet segment. So what happens, if the area has a combination of both p2p(Mesh for example) and also an Ethernet segment which has a few routers connected. And again a router from the Ethernet segment connected to the router in the mesh network. Does the DR and BDR still hold good? Does the routers in the mesh send their LSA 1 to the DR present in the multiaccess network(Ethernet segment)?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A router participates in DR/BDRs elections when the interface type is set to broadcast. This happens for every interface that is set to broadcast.  It doesn't matter what the actual media is.

Elections do not take place on p2p links (if they are configured as such).

In either case, the area ID has no bearing on whether the election takes place or not.